# create google cloud workflow with cloud scheduler trigger with payload using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-scheduler

How do i create google cloud workflow with cloud schduler trigger with payload using terraform. By Payload i mean workflow arguments.

Didnt find anything in terraform documentation about creating google cloud workflow with cloud schduler trigger with payload using terraform by Payload i mean workflow arguments. I have tried http trigger for workflow but there is no way to pass workflow arguments to google worklflow.

Following is terraform configuration i tried for http trigger to google workflow.

```
`provider "google" {
    project = "<project-id>"
    region = "us-central1"
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "topic" {
  name = "job-topic-1"
}

data "google_compute_default_service_account" "default" {
}

resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "job" {
  name             = "test-job1"
  description      = "test http job"
  schedule         = "* * * * *"
  time_zone        = "America/New_York"
  attempt_deadline = "320s"

  retry_config {
    retry_count = 1
  }

  http_target {
    http_method = "POST"
    uri         = "https://workflowexecutions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/cp-ai-demo-v2/locations/us-central1/workflows/workflow-2/executions"
    body        = jsonencode("{\"argument\":\"{\"text1\":\"test1\",\"text2\":\"test1\"}}")

    oauth_token {
      service_account_email = data.google_compute_default_service_account.default.email
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: Outside Terraform, your use case is not clear. What do you want to achieve and where are you stuck?

Comment: Workflow has execution API to run a workflow. Cloud Scheduler can call HTTP endpoint with a body and with Access Token security. There is no magic sauce to build all in one declaration, but you can reproduce the architecture step by step yourselves

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I suppose the question is looking for an example Workflows that is triggered by a cloud scheduler (with a payload) in an http call.